# Confusing extends keyword in definiton of Pick mapped type

Tags: typescript

The definition of type [Pick](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.9.2/lib/lib.d.ts#L1373) is:

```
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]: T[P];
};
```

**Question:** Why do we use `extends` here? Is it just not the best name pick for `extends` keyword in this case and it should be something like `exists in`?

Because the name of `extends` keyword communicates to me that we take K keys supplied as a second parameter and then we extend keys of T. So, basically we get K keys that we supplied as a second parameter, plus all the keys of T. Which sums to `*Length of T* + *amount of K keys*` keys as a second parameter. Which means that the amount of keys supplied for the second parameter is at least the same as the amount of keys supplied for the first. And how can we Pick from the first parameter if we might have keys as a second parameter which do not exist on T?

Comment: `extends` here is the syntax for specifying [constraints on generic parameter types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints), in means that whatever type you pass as `K` must be assignable to `keyof T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extends denotes a constraint on a type in this context. The confusing part might be around what is considered to extend what.

Consider clasic OOP, all derived types are also of the base type, so in effect we can assign more objects to a base type reference than to a derived type reference, in effect a base type reference is more permissive then a derived type reference.

Lets apply this logic to Typescript types and lets start with `string` and string literal types, the following relation is true :

```
'prop' extends string
```

The more restrictive type extends the more general version. Appling the same logic to a union we get

```
number extends number | string
```

Again the more restrictive type is said to extend the more general type. Moving forward to unions of sting literals it follows that this relation will also be true

```
 'foo' extends 'foo' | 'bar' |'baz'
```

But since `keyof T` is a union of all string literal types to expres that `K` must be a type more restrictive than `keyof T` it follows we should write

```
 K extends keyof T
```

This will în effect make `K` one of the types in the union of string literal types representing the properties of `T`.

We are not restricted to just one key though, since this relation is also true :

```
'bar' | 'foo' extends   'bar' | 'foo' |'baz'
```

Since the union on the left is more restrictive the relation is true, and we can pick more then one property using `Pick`

Comment: I find this overloading of 'extends' keyword to be a confusing choice. It applies OOP terminology to a non-OOP situation.  I suggest it makes more sense to think of as "T is a subset of U".

Comment: I agree with @michaeljsalo, I found `extends` confusing. It's ethymology and the meaning in OOP context suggests the opposite of what it actualy does express. Reading this Q&A, I convergently came to `is subset of` (or `satisfy the constraints of`) as a better term to understand the purpose of `extends`.